# Angular cascading dropdowns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create two drop downs one with topic and the other one with videos. The videos one is going to be filter by the topics. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
        <md-input-container flex>
            <label>Topic</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.topic" required ng-change="getVideosByTopicId(selected.topic)">
                <md-option ng-repeat="topic in topics" value="{{topic.TopicID}}">{{topic.TopicName}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
            <label>Video</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.video" required >
                <md-option ng-repeat="video in videos" value="{{video.VideoID}}">{{video.Name}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

And this is the controller

```
function getVideosByTopicId(topicId) {
    return $http.post(baseUrl + 'Test/getVideosByTopicId', topicId).then(function (response) {
        return $.parseJSON(response.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: if everything is fine with your js code then assign the response to $scope.videos use that in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<md-select ng-model="type" >
    <md-option ng-value="k" data-ng-repeat="(k,v) in videos">{{ k }}</md-option>
</md-select>
    <md-select ng-model="metrics" >
   <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in level2">{{ t }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rI3AsC2plZ3w82WRBjAo?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. Which one is better to use: watch or ng - change. Could you please show me an example with ng-change.

Comment: ng-change is the suggested way

Comment: what do you want to do with ng-changed?

Comment: Populate the second combo box when the first one changes

Comment: @user6934713 yes you can do taht via ng-change and send the request